# URL works in Browser but not get response from web Client or Web Request

Tags: c#, winforms, httpwebrequest, webrequest, webresponse

I have an issue regarding response from server. (returns 403 forbidden).

When I am checking the same url in browser I can see the the page.

I have written the below code for getting response.

Same Code I am execute in my local PC, It works fine.

```
 HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(RequestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                request.Timeout = 600000;
                request.Accept = "*/*";
                request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0";

WebResponse response;
                try
                {
                    response = request.GetResponse();
                    string StatusDescription = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription;

                    if (StatusDescription.ToLower() == "ok")
                    {
                        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                        //XmlDocument XmlResponse = new XmlDocument();
                        //XmlResponse.Load(dataStream);            
                        //XmlResponse.Save(Server.MapPath("~/XMLResponse.xml"));
                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        responseFromServer = responseFromServer.Replace("&nbsp;", "");
                        responseFromServer = responseFromServer.Replace("&", "&amp;");
                        reader.Close();
                        dataStream.Dispose();
                        response.Close();
                        responseFromServer = GetStringsBetweenTags(responseFromServer, "<head>", "</head>");
                        return responseFromServer;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //To Do : add code for notify error via email
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {                   
                    WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(webclient.OpenRead(RequestUrl)))
                    {
                        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        responseFromServer = responseFromServer.Replace("&nbsp;", "");
                        responseFromServer = responseFromServer.Replace("&", "&amp;");
                        reader.Close();
                        webclient.Dispose();
                        responseFromServer = GetStringsBetweenTags(responseFromServer, "<head>", "</head>");
                        return responseFromServer;

                    }

                }
```

Comment: Where is the code for the request ?

Comment: Can you navigate to the site on the server using whatever browser it has installed?

Comment: yes, Navigate the url in IE-9 and Firefox, Both working fine.

Comment: @JamieTownsend added Request Code.

Answer (score 4):

Download Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

Then navigate to the URL and look at the headers. Then look at the headers your application is sending.  The URL you are *POSTING* to are clearly preventing certain requests.